# No disk or partitions mounted when installing ubuntu server 18.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ubuntu-server, unmounting

I am trying to install ubuntu server using a bootable USB on a **DELL EMC PowerEdge R640 Server** with (1TB HDD and 800GB SSD), in step 7 / 13, when I have to choose the installation disk, there is no mounted disk available!!. So how I can mount the disks in order to complete the installation.

Thanks

**Edit**

The 7th step on *Ubuntu-server 18.04.3* is equivalent to the 5th step in the  official tutorial: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#8 - Here I can't see any mounted disk.

Comment: The official tutorial https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#0 does not refer to the install source in step 7. Please provide the URL of whatever third-party install process you are using by clicking [edit] and putting that URL in the question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/dz/fr/dzbsdt1/sln307603/dell-poweredge-how-to-create-a-virtual-disk-through-the-system-setup-on-14g-servers?lang=en), In order to mount disks you have first to create a virtual disk for your connected disk from the **System Setup** as explained in the above attached link.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. This seems like useful information. However, you may want to consider editing your answer and quoting the (basic) steps you found helped in providing a solution to your problem. Links can become obsolete very quickly.